# Какие есть библиотеки на С++ для создания текстового интерфейса?

Tags: c++, ncurses

Есть ли на С++ библиотеки наподобии curses? Можно ли эти библиотеки (или curses) на mac?

Comment: эмм.... а как на счёт, сюрприз-сюрприз, curses?.. Если C-API не устраивает, то у ncurses есть свои биндинги для плюсов, правда абсолютно недокументированные, так что предлагается изучение исходников... Про mac, — не понимаю, кто бы мог запретить использовать curses на оном.

Comment: Ну вод для кого написано: "аналоги curses"? Ну вот что не понятного в слове "аналоги"?

Comment: А в чём смысл поиска аналогов? Просто академический интерес или curses чем-то не нравится?..  /зануда мод/ слово "аналоги" в вопросе не упоминается...

Comment: Тоесть про mac прочитал, а слово "аналоги" нет? Что касается "зачем да почему" - не считаю нужным разъяснять, тк вопрос не в этом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть еще [S-Lang](http://www.jedsoft.org/slang/index.html). Вроде бы работает и под [Mac OSX](http://macappstore.org/s-lang/).

Answer (score 1):

> Можно ли эти библиотеки (или curses) на mac?

Можно. В MacPorts есть порт ncurses:

```
$ sudo port search ncurses
ncurses @6.1 (devel)
    emulation of curses in System V Release 4.0
```